# How to answer this interview question about problems affecting UK companies

Tags: interviewing

I recently had a telephone interview and I was bombarded with the following question -

What are the problems affecting UK companies over the past two years? What do you think is the biggest problem and which area it is affecting the most?

I was clue less about how to answer this question. I do read business news everyday but still could not think of any suitable answer for this question. Any idea guys? OR give me pointers as what should I do/read to gain knowledge about this kind of questions.

Comment: Seems like the question did it's job. It's one thing to read the news every day, and another to _read_ the news every day. Just consuming information isn't helpful if you don't think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Are there any common themes in those business pages: Is it about slow growth, is it about immigration, is it about finding qualified workers? There are lots of possible answers where the key is how do you back up whatever answer you give.

I can remember more than a few months ago being in a room where someone mentioned how they was so much job hopping being done in the UK that people stayed in a role for 18-24 months so that trying to train a replacement didn't seem that feasible since there wasn't much time after the person got used to the job to train the next person. This to my mind would be a suitable start where one could go into more detail for those roles where training is hard to do as being the most affected since not everyone enjoys trial by fire in a new role.

The key here is to look at the big picture in terms of what challenges does the government have with the economy: Is it a lack of jobs? Is it a lack of people staying in a job for more than a few years? Is it that growth isn't happening? There are lots of different questions one could take here where the key is how well do you see any issue and can you explain this in a good way.